I need to install ethtool version 6.9 on to Ubuntu 20.04.1 . Is this possible?
Current ethtool version on this machine is 5.4. But need 6.9 due to a bug fix in its ability to advertise ethernet speeds and duplex settings. the 5.4 version simply rejects the number but a fix was released in January.
Is it possible to install this new version without updating Ubuntu?
Settings for enp152s0f1np1:
        Supported ports: [ Backplane ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full 
                                10000baseKR/Full 
                                25000baseCR/Full 
                                25000baseKR/Full 
                                25000baseSR/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: None BaseR RS
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseKX/Full 
                                10000baseKR/Full 
                                25000baseCR/Full 
                                25000baseKR/Full 
                                25000baseSR/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: None
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Direct Attach Copper
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000004 (4)
                               link
        Link detected: yes
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION            
wlx801f02f93201  wifi      connected    eduroam User          
enp152s0f1np1    ethernet  connected    netplan-enp152s0f1np1 
enp153s0f1       ethernet  connected    netplan-enp153s0f1    
usb0             ethernet  connected    Wired connection 3    
enp152s0f0np0    ethernet  unavailable  --                    
enp153s0f0       ethernet  unavailable  -- 


root@machine:/etc/netplan# ethtool -s enp152s0f1np1 autoneg on speed 25000 duplex full
Cannot advertise speed 25000 duplex full
root@machine:/etc/netplan#


Your details imply you've not applied security fixes since 2020 or Jan 2021 (ie. 20.04.1 !) ...   It's not safe to use that machine online or connected to the internet, please apply security fixes asap.  This page (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/) will show the ISO release date of 20.04.2, but installed systems upgraded prior to the ISO release date.

Yes - I had the same issue and was able to do this successfully
ethtool 6.9 is in the Oracular repo. In order to install ethtool from that repo without upgrading any other packages on the system, we must pin ethtool to Oracular
I followed these instructions and modified them for ethtool and the correct OS names, and it worked well for me: https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-install-packages-from-a-newer-distribution-without-installing-unwanted-6584fa93208f

It is possible to compile ethtool version 6.5 from source.
That version will run just fine on Ubuntu 20.04.1  and allow setting speeds to 250000 and beyond.
